Shadow view is getting darker every time the content is visible in CardView attempt of UITableView
I'm trying to achieve a Card View layout with UITableView in Swift UIKit. When I use the below code, i get what i want but every time the cell comes to the visible area the background and the shadow gets darker and darker.
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    let whiteRoundedView : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(15, 15, self.view.frame.size.width - 30, 90))
    whiteRoundedView.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
    whiteRoundedView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    whiteRoundedView.layer.cornerRadius = 3.0
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1)
    whiteRoundedView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    
    if !cell.contentView.subviews.contains(whiteRoundedView) {
        cell.contentView.addSubview(whiteRoundedView) //<- AAA
    }
    cell.contentView.sendSubviewToBack(whiteRoundedView)
}

AAA seems to call every time no matter the check because every time it gets passed.
Can someone suggest me the best approach to achieve this???


Cells. Are. Reused. So you are adding a white rounded view even to a cell that already has one (or ten, or 100). No cell ever passes the condition ("does this cell contain whiteRoundedView?") because you are making a different white rounded view each time; no cell can possibly contain it because, guess what, you just created it.

please don't post huge 144 dpi images, it looks horrible and gives me a headache.

As @matt said, cells are reused, which means willDisplay cell will be called multiple times during the cell's life cycle, and whiteRoundedView also be added multiple times.
You can try this approach. By doing so below, you're making sure that the whiteRoundedView will be added only once.
//If your cell was created from XIB/Storyboard
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    //Put the code for making shadow here
    let whiteRoundedView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(15, 15, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 30, 90))
    ...
}

//If you manually create with code
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier { 
    ...
    //Put the code for making shadow here
    let whiteRoundedView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(15, 15, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width - 30, 90))
    ...
}

Notice: Every if condition within a cell should pair with else, especially about the cell's appearance. Or you will encounter the unexpected behavior.

To achieve the output i expected, firstly I created another custom class as below.
class ShadowView: UIView {

   override var bounds: CGRect {
       didSet {
           setupShadow()
       }
   }

   private func setupShadow() {
       self.layer.cornerRadius = 10
       self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 3)
       self.layer.shadowRadius = 3
       self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3
       self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, byRoundingCorners: .allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10, height: 10)).cgPath
       self.layer.shouldRasterize = true
       self.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    }
}

And then in my UITableViewCell I added this ShadowView to my bgView and with constraints.
class CardViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    -------
    -------

    var bgView = UIView()
    var shadowBg = ShadowView()

    -------
    -------

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
         super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    
         ------
         ------
         configureShadowView()
    }

    -------
    -------

    func configureShadowView() {
        bgView.addSubview(shadowBg)
        shadowBg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        shadowBg.layer.backgroundColor = CGColor(colorSpace: CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(), components: [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0])
        bgView.sendSubviewToBack(shadowBg)
    
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shadowBg.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.topAnchor),
            shadowBg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.leadingAnchor),
            shadowBg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.trailingAnchor),
            shadowBg.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bgView.bottomAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

Then I removed the below entire block I posted in the Question above
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
}

